# Summing 1 Column As Two Separate Values Depending on Another Value in the Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a column A, and a column Z.

I'm doing a SELECT on this table, summing A.

I want to sum(A) as "B" if column Z = 1, and sum(A) as "C" if column Z = 2. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case statement `SUM`s...

```
Select  Sum(Case When Z = 1 Then A Else 0 End) As B,
        Sum(Case When Z = 2 Then A Else 0 End) As C
From    TableName
```